# how can I post data into an array of objects in react with an input? using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've 2 inputs and i want to post data in my api. how can I do with hooks?
I can post information of a single fields, but not in an array of objects

these are my inputs:

```
              <TextField
                  name="material"
                  onChange={(e) => setProFields((prev) => ({
                    ...prev,
                    [e.materiales_consumo.material]: e.target.value,
                  }))}
                  variant="outlined"
                  label="Material"
                  data-id={index}
                  type="text"
                  value={newPro.materiales_consumo[]}
                />
                <TextField
                  name="magnitud"
                  onChange={(e) => setProFields((prev) => ({
                    ...prev,
                    [e.materiales_consumo.magnitud]: e.target.value,
                  }))}
                  label="Magnitud"
                  variant="outlined"
                  data-id={index}
                  type="text"
                  value={newPro.materiales_consumo.magnitud}
```

In postman i post information like that:
               {
                      "description":"//",
                      "family":"//",
                      "line":"//",
                      "model":"//",
                      "plz1":"//",
                      "plz2":"//",
                      "plz3":"//",
                       "materiales_consumo":[{"material":"String","magnitud":Number}, 
                                             {"material":"String","magnitud":Number}]
              }

And there is my state hook
 const [newPro, setProFields] = useState({
    description: '',
    family: '',
    line: '',
    model: '',
    plz1: '',
    plz2: '',
    plz3: '',
    materiales_consumo: [],
  });

Comment: What have you tried and what problem do you encounter ?

Comment: how do you send the post request to your server?